# recursive binary search, biesction by slicing

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search

I'm trying to implement a binary search on a list of integers using recursion and "eliminating" half of the items by slicing the list each time. I wrote some of it and I'm kind of stuck in the part where I'm supposed to return "True" if the target value is met. Iteratively I'd check if 'left' is greater than 'right' but I want to keep the functions' arguments as simple as possible.

```
def binary_search(iterable, target):

    left_index = 0
    right_index = len(iterable)
    mid = (left_index + right_index) // 2

    if iterable[mid] == target:
        return True
    elif iterable[mid] < target:
        iterable = iterable[mid:right_index]
        print(iterable)
        binary_search(iterable,target)
    elif iterable[mid] > target:
        iterable = iterable[left_index:mid]
        print(iterable)
        binary_search(iterable,target)
```

Comment: *"Iteratively I'd check if 'left' is greater than 'right' but I want to keep the functions' arguments as simple as possible."* - Why would 'left' ever be greater than 'right'?  In order for a binary search to work, the input must be sorted.

Comment: Because that'd be the condition to return False, as it'd mean the item isn't in the list, maybe I explained it poorly tho

Comment: if you want to see your return just add `return` before all your function calls in both elifs also you don't need 2 elifs if your input is sorted. But that's only so you won't get `None` you still have a multitude of issues with this if someone puts in a number that is not in the list you get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below returns `False` if the value is not found; otherwise it returns the index. The binary search executes recursively.

The key addition to your code is `return`ing your function calls.  I added some `return a+b if a != False else a` logic, to handle returning `False` if the value isn't in the iterable.

```py
def binary_search(iterable, target):
    # if the list is down to one element, and it isn't the target, return False
    if len(iterable) == 1 and iterable[0] != target: return False
        
    left_index = 0
    right_index = len(iterable)
    mid = (left_index + right_index) // 2

    if iterable[mid] == target:
        return mid
    elif iterable[mid] < target:
        iterable = iterable[mid:right_index]
        v = binary_search(iterable,target)
        # if v is not False, add it to the left side of the window and return
        # else return False
        return v + mid if v != False else v
    elif iterable[mid] > target:
        iterable = iterable[left_index:mid]
        v = binary_search(iterable,target)
        return v + left_index if v != False else v
```

Comment: I want to return True if the number is in the list and false if it isn't just for starters, right now my search stops at certain stages without returning anything. For example, if I call the function like this: print(binary_search([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],7))
I get this printed out:
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[6, 7]
None